# NSXMLParser is not invoking foundIgnorableWhitespace

Tags: ios, xml, nsxmlparser, dtd

I'm trying to detect ignorable whitespace in an xml document, but my delegate's parser:foundIgnorableWhitespace: method is never being invoked.  I've tried with contrived examples that include ignorable whitespace as well, but it isn't working for those either.

This is a test document I've tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><!DOCTYPE library [  <!ELEMENT library (book+)>  <!ELEMENT book (text)>  <!ELEMENT text (#PCDATA)>]><library><book><text>lorem ipsum</text>      </book></library>
```

The whitespace after the text element should be ignorable (in my understanding of what that means) because a book is not allowed to contain any #PCDATA, but it is being passed to foundCharacters rather than foundIgnorableWhitespace.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Dumb question: does your parser's .h include the `NSXMLPARSERDELEGATE` protocol?

Comment: What do you mean?  I did specify the protocol in the class declaration like MyDelegate : NSObject<NSXMLParserDelegate>.  Is there also some include I should have?  I'd think Foundation.h would cover it.